# What makes Obsidian edges sharper than other glass?

Tags: material-science, amorphous-solids, glass

Obsidian is a [volcanic glass](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obsidian) with a reputation for being *extremely* sharp. Some surgeons use obsidian scalpels rather than high-quality steel surgical scalpels.

At the same time, glass blades are used for [Microtomes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microtome) and can even be [Manufactured](http://www.usask.ca/biology/scopes/glassknifemaker.JPG) on site.

Is obsidian really sharper than other glasses? If so, what properties make obsidian sharper? Why can't we make special glass for use in scalpels that's as sharp as obsidian?

Comment: I don't have an answers, but it needn't be a matter of "can't". If it is cheaper to harvest naturally occurring obsidian than to manufacture glass with the same cleavage properties it might be purely a matter of economics.